# The time zone in the CnosDB log is incorrect

Tags: database, time-series, timezone, cnosdb

The time recorded in the log is eight hours later than the actual time

CnosDB version: a20d094

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVBDi.png)

How can I solve this problem, is there any relevant configuration? Or is this a bug?

The time zone in the log is consistent with the host time zone

Comment: The time zone in the log is in UTC by the looks of it - that's what the "Z" means. I don't know what you mean by "the actual time version: a20d094".